# Change the way async validators run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

Is it possible to update the model first, and then run the validator? I've an async validator, which runs on update of an input (type `range`).

What I want is to update the value on the HTML template first, and then run the validator. The default behaviour is to run the validator first, and then update the model if the the validation is complete.

Please refer to the below snippet:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.value = 0;
  })
  .directive('validateValue', ($http) => {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: false,
      link: linkFn
    };

    function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs, modelCtrl) {
      modelCtrl.$asyncValidators.validValue = (m, v) => {
        return $http.get('https://httpbin.org/delay/1');
      };
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <form>
      <input type="range" ng-model="value" ng-model-options="{debounce: 100}" validate-value> {{value}}
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `allowInvalid: true`. Logically this make sense - if you want change value before validation you should allow invalid values in model.

```
ng-model-options="{debounce: 100, allowInvalid: true}"
```

Comment: Thank you! I used `allowInvalid` before, but wasn't sure if it really does that due to the `debounce`.